# put pagination for dijango 1.8 web project?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pagination

I implemented Django (1.8) web project and use MongoDB for my database. I have view and it show table data. I want to put pagination for that table.

This is my **view.py** class

```
@login_required
def key_view(request):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.product.serial_key
    cursor = db.find()
    context = {'key': cursor}
    return render(request, 'marcador/key_list_form.html',context)
```

My **Model.py** class

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Key_Gen(models.Model):
    key_beging_code =models.DecimalField('Brand_name +Pack_size' ,max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    key_quantity    =models.DecimalField("key Quantity" ,max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    key_code        =models.CharField('key Code' ,max_length=50 , unique=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField('public', default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created',auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated',auto_now_add=True)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name='key_Gen'
        verbose_name_plural='keys_Gen'
        ordering = ['-date_created']


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.key_code)



    def get_key_code(self,x,y):
        alist = []
        x = algo(int(x),int(y),alist)
        keys =x.id_generator()
        return keys
```

**URL.py** file

```
  url(r'^view_key/$', 'marcador.views.key_view',
    name='marcador_key_view'),
```

**Template** file

```
       {% block content %}
       <table border="1">
                <th width="100">Product Code</th>
                <th width="100">Serial Key</th>
            {% for x in key %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ x.b_p_code  }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.key }}</td>
                </tr>

         {% endfor %}
         </table>
  {% endblock %}
```

I am new comer to Dijango web programming , please kindly expect some expert help.

current  view of my page.

[image]

After update code according to first answer .

**View.py**

```
@login_required
def key_view(request):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.product.serial_key
    cursor = db.find()

    paginator = Paginator(cursor, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        cursor = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        cursor = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        cursor = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {'key': cursor})
```

now give following error.

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_key/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'marcador',
 'crispy_forms',
 'bootstrap_pagination')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/umayanga/Desktop/view_site/serialKey_gen_site/marcador/templates/marcador/key_list_form.html, error at line 13
   object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

   3 : {% block title %}Key List{% endblock %}



   4 : 



   5 : {% block heading %}



   6 :   <h2>Keys</h2>



   7 : {% endblock %}



   8 : 



   9 : {% block content %}



   10 :    <table border="1">



   11 :             <th width="100">Product Code</th>



   12 :             <th width="100">Serial Key</th>



   13 :          {% for x in key %} 



   14 :             <tr>



   15 :                 <td>{{ x.b_p_code  }}</td>



   16 :                 <td>{{ x.key }}</td>



   17 :             </tr>



   18 : 



   19 :      {% endfor %}



   20 :      </table>



   21 : 



   22 : {% endblock %}



   23 : 


Traceback:
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/view_site/serialKey_gen_site/marcador/views.py" in key_view
  104.     return render_to_response('marcador/key_list_form.html', {'key': cursor})
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  39.         content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  162.             len_values = len(values)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/serialKey_gen_site/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in __len__
  117.         return len(self.object_list)

Exception Type: TypeError at /view_key/
Exception Value: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Paginator
```

From:

```
django.core.paginator
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/

Comment: please ,can you help how to put this  code ? I am new comer programming , I am difficult to understand how to change my code.

Comment: Sir , i put your code to view.py but it give me error now. :-(

Comment: I update and post my error , please can you do any help for me. ?